# Сервер не находит js-файлы ckeditor

Tags: python, django, heroku, static, gunicorn

Проблема в том, что вся статика отдается нормально кроме js-файлов ckeditor, вследствие чего самого редактора на сайте нет. Консоль браузера выводит следующее:[image: консоль]:

Вот настройки из settings.py: `

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/'

import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

`
Буду признателен за любую наводку в сторону правильного решения)

Comment: `manage.py collectstatic` запускали?

Comment: @Andrey он автоматически запускается heroku насколько я знаю

Comment: А попробуйте еще путь изменить на такой `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/'`

Comment: @Andrey все так же

Comment: @Andrey помогите...

Comment: но у меня больше нет идей..